# Doing image compression with Neural Network AutoEncoders

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, compression, tensorflow

I wanted to create an image compressor using Machine Learning and started work on an "AutoEncoder". This is a type of Neural Network which takes in the image and creates a compressed vector form.

It has two parts: encoder and decoder. `encoder` converts the images to vector form. `decoder` tries to re-create the image only from the vector created by the *encoder*.

This is how it looks like:

[image: AutoEncoder]

I have made the `encoder` a stack of Convolutional layers along with some MaxPooling2D ones. However, there is just a tiny problem.

The model performs well on any Image but it can be significantly improved.

For starters, the encoding dimension is **too high!** Right now with my calculations, I am getting a compression of 5 Mb -> 5Kb which is *very* lossy as the compression factor becomes x1000.

```
    import os
    import tensorflow as tf
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras import backend as K
    import numpy as np
    from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    images_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/Images/" # /{}.jpg".format(i)
    EPOCHS = 50

image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(images_dir),
                                                     batch_size=1,
                                                     shuffle=False,
                                                     target_size=(600, 400),
                                                     class_mode='input')
#*****************************
# ENCODER STARTS HERE
#*****************************

input_img = Input(shape=(600, 400, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)                                    #ALl filters are upped by 16 and kernel size of encoder is 
x = Conv2D(80, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)                   # also upped by 1 and downed in decoder 
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(144, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((1, 1), padding='same')(x)

# *************************
#  DECODER STARTS HERE 
#****************************

x = Conv2D(48, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)             # DEfault = (2,2)
x = UpSampling2D((1, 1))(x)                               # Default = (2,2) 
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

    checkpoint_dir= "/content/drive/My Drive/Checkp_autoenc/"
    checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
                                 save_weights_only=True)

    autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

    autoencoder.summary()

    autoencoder.fit_generator(train_data_gen,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint])

    decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(train_data_gen)
```

I had decided the filter and kernel values on a whim. But they can be adjusted to encompass more information so that the compression factor is reduced. As an example, here is what a sample image looks like:

As you can see clearly, this is very lossy and pixelated because the compression factor is really high. Also, the convolutional layers can also be flattened and the non-linearization function `ReLu` may be applied.

But I want some feedback from the experts to determine what areas are actually to be improved and what should be simply left alone. So I appreciate some constructive feedback and advice!

[image: Very Lossy!]

After a lot of studying and research, I managed to change the model sufficiently enough to produce a picture of *significantly* better quality images. But can it still be improved? Keep in mind the compression is x1000 meaning Image has been compressed over a 1000.

[image: Improvement]

Comment: It appears that your indentation is incorrect at your `import`s at the top. Please fix this.